# animate background image with CSS over gradient?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS attempting to infinitely move a background image overlaid on a background gradient by animating its position. The image isn't animating. I based it off an example here without the gradient.  https://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css

Suggestions appreciated.

```
  /*Home header scrolling background pattern animation*/
  @keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }



#homeheader{
background-color: #53DFFD; 
background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -o-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
background-size: cover, cover;
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
animation: animatedBackground 4s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you were to add the HTML to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the gradient, it's the `background-size: cover` attribute. You can't animate the `background-position` attribute with a `background-size: cover` attribute on.

```css
  /*Home header scrolling background pattern animation*/
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

#homeheader{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #53DFFD; 
  background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
  background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
  background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), -o-radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
  background:url("http://www.johnrockson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/expandsnaps.png"), radial-gradient(circle, #53DFFD, #6960F5); 
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 4s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="homeheader"></div>
```